# What are the names given to the Devi in the Tripura Upanishad of the Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda, shakti, devi

Devi or Shakti is the feminine form of the Divine.

What are the names given to the Devi in the [Tripura Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Upanishad) of the Rig Veda?

Answer (score 1):

The sixth shloka of the Tripura Upanishad gives the following names to the Devi:

> मदन्तिका मानिनी मङला च सुभगा सा सुन्दरी शुद्धमत्ता ।
>
> लज्जा
> मतिस्तुष्टिरिष्टा च पुष्टा लक्ष्मीरुमा ललिता लालपन्ती ।। ६ ।।

[The Divine Mother] is variously known as

> Madantika, joyous;
>
> Manini, proud;
>
> Mangala, auspicious;
>
> and Subhaga, prosperous.

And she is

> Sundari, beautiful;
>
> Shuddhamatta, pure;
>
> Lajja, modest;
>
> Mati, intelligent;
>
> Tushti, satisfied;
>
> Ishta, desired;
>
> Pushta, nourished;
>
> Lakshmi, wealthy;
>
> Uma, splendorous;
>
> and Lalita, eloquent.

Reference used: https://www.academia.edu/19972388/Tripura_Upanishad_English_Translation_Prabuddha_Bharata_January_2016